# R not attached in VS Code on Win10

Tags: python, r, visual-studio-code

I am recently switching from RStudio to VS Code. I have installed R extension in VS Code, but when I open VS Code and R terminal, R cannot be loaded. I followed coip's method but still cannot get R loaded:
[image]

##############################################################################
I followed coip's suggstion and R is successfully activated. In another of my laptop (Win), R could be activated without any issue. But when I check the `settings.json` file, there is no such specification as `r.rterm.windows`. **I want to ask why my laptop could successfuly load R in VS Code without having to include those code snippet suggested by coip?**

Below is the `settings.json` in my laptop:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Patrick Wen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.rmd": "markdown"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your complete `settings.json` file? For R-related parameters, you only have `r.rpath.windows`?

Comment: @coip yes, this is my complete `settings.json` file. The `defaultSettings.json` file is much longer, where there is `"r.rpath.windows": "",` and `"r.rterm.windows": "",`. But `defaultSettings.json` seems not editable in my VS Code.

Comment: Okay, yeah, don't mess around with the `defaultsettings.json` file, just the `settings.json` file. See my answer below and let me know if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your complete `settings.json`, you're missing common parameters such as `r.rpath.windows` and the `--r-binary` under `r.rterm.option`. I believe adding those, with the same path to R that you currently have for `r.rpath.windows` should fix your issue.

Here is a typical setup that you can copy and paste into your JSON settings, which you can access via View > Command Palette > Preferences: Open Settings (JSON):

```
{
// R Options
"r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe",
"r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe",
"r.lsp.path": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe",
"r.lsp.debug": true,
"r.lsp.diagnostics": true,
"r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
"r.rterm.option": [
    "--no-save",
    "--no-restore",
    "--r-binary=C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe"
],
"r.bracketedPaste": true,
"r.sessionWatcher": true
}
```

Note: some of those are just preferences (e.g. `r.bracketedPaste`).

So you can try to add all of the above or some of the above, save your JSON settings, and relaunch VSCode, until the problem is fixed.

If that doesn't work, let's try setting up an integrated profile, by adding the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
   "PowerShell": {
       "source": "PowerShell",
       "icon": "terminal-powershell"
   },
   "Command Prompt": {
       "path": [
          "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
          "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
   },
   "R": {
       "path": [
           "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe"
       ]
   },
},
```

You can also try making R your default terminal by adding the following line above too:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "R",
```

Comment: I followed your comments except for adding `"r.plot.useHttpgd": true,`. I demonstrate my screeshot in the revised question. Any ideas? Thank you indeed.

Comment: Let's first try adding an integrated profile to the `json.settings`. See everything after "If that doesn't work" in my revised answer above. Otherwise, it seems VSCode cannot find your R.exe, which might be an OS-level PATH variable problem. What happens when you click on "R: (not attached)" in the bottom bar?

Comment: Thank you for the suggested further revisions but that still did not work. I have revised my question. Thank you.

Comment: What does the rest of the error message popup say: "Change setting r.rterm.windows..."? It seems VSCode doesn't know where R is on your computer. Have you confirmed that R.exe is actually at the path you list above? Press Win + R to open Run and then enter `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\R.exe` and press "OK". Does an R terminal pop up?

Comment: Yes, R popped up. The full error message is shown in revised question. Thanks again.

Comment: I think there was a mistake in the JSON settings I had provided you before, having `r.term.windows` instead of `r.rterm.windows`. See my revised answer under `/// R Options` above, update your `json.settings`, save, and then relaunch VSCode and let me know if that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I have also a New Question. Highly appreciated as well if you are interested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72236908/r-objects-not-in-global-environment-in-vs-code

Comment: New Q on Python terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72237193/add-python-terminal-in-vs-code

Comment: May I ask why `settings.json` in another of my laptop could load R without having to include the code you suggested? More details in edited question. Thx.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure without knowing more information, but it could be due to different installation locations for R on each device or, more accurately, existing %PATH% variables on the operating system level on your laptop already being in tune with the R.exe location whereas that was not the case on your other device.