# R Objects not in global environment in VS Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use VS Code to run R. When I open R terminal in VS Code, I cannot find R icon on the left most column.
[image]

I created a .r file, loaded that into VS Code, and the R icon appeared. But do I have to load a .r file in order to let VS Code show the R icon? Is it possible to activate this R icon without loading any .r file?

Question 2:

When I loaded the .r file, I could see a menu called "Global Environment". However, nothing appears here when I create an object either using the loaded .r file or directly in the terminal. I want to know how could the created objects be demonstrated in "Global Environment"?
[image]

Comment: Already installed _Extensions > R_?

Comment: Yes, I have already installed R extension for visual studio code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Question 1, try to specify R as your default terminal in your JSON settings `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "R",` or specify R as your default language `"files.defaultLanguage": "r",`.

For Question 2, when you click on "R: (not attached)" on the bottom bar or input `.vsc.attach()` into the terminal, your objects should start showing up in your global environment.

Comment: For everyone else who is just starting with VSC, here are the JSON settings. https://semicolon.dev/vscode/how-to-open-settings-json

Answer (score 0):

run this command .vsc.attach() in your R interactive terminal before fresh starting the R notebook.