# Add Python terminal in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run Python from VS Code. I have already activated python through the terminal. However, in the terminal selector in the lower right of the screen, I cannot find Python terminal option there:
[image]

I wish to ask how could I make Python terminal visible here so that the next time I wish to switch terminal to Python, I do not have to load a .py file but could just selecting Python terminal directly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Python terminal. If you are asking about loading Python shell you just have to type `python` into your terminal to load the Python shell

Answer (score 2):

Python terminals aren't really a thing. If you want to run a .py file, do `$ python [filename].py` or `$ python3 [filename].py`. If you want to just run commands, open a Python shell by doing `$ python` or `$ python3`

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal and type "python -u".
Hit the enter key.
Bhoom! You're good to use Python shell in VS Code.

[image: Python Shell in VS Code]