# R fails to attach to the terminal in certain workspaces in Visual Studio Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I have been using RStudio for a while and recently switched to Visual Studio Code.  Until recently, I had no issues opening any files or workspaces, but now when I open some workspaces it seems that R fails to attach to the terminal.  I get no errors when I click "R: (not attached)" and ".vsc.attach()" shows up in the terminal like normal but nothing changes. [Screenshot of terminal after attempting to attach R to terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFu40.png).  If I open a new Visual Studio Code window and open a single file, not in a saved workspace, it opens normally and R attaches without any input from me. [Screenshot of terminal after opening a new window and file not in a workspace.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqXsH.png)  If I open the same file, not in a saved workspace, and then save the workspace, R is no longer attached and will no longer attach to the terminal.  I tried using the fix from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72143693/r-not-attached-in-vs-code-on-win10) and added the code from the answer but nothing changed once again.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I started with a fresh install of Visual Studio Code from the website, not the Microsoft store, and did not sign in or sync my settings.  I went through the process of setting up R again and used "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\x64\R.exe" as Rpath and Rterm, which seems to be working so far.  I will update my answer if the issue comes back or if I find another solution.