# How to show work space in Visual Code code for R

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use R in Visual Code with the package [R Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r).

I can use R inside of Visual Code to store vectors and make plots like this:

```r
test <- c(10, 12, 15)
plot(test)
```

However, the workspace remains empty which makes me unable to view the things that I have stored.

[image]

I can see that R is marked as `not attached` in the status bar below:

[image]

When I click on it I get `Error in .vsc.attach() : could not find function ".vsc.attach"`:

[image]

I have tried to edit my `settings.json` according to things I found here on SO (like [R fails to attach to the terminal in certain workspaces in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965488/r-fails-to-attach-to-the-terminal-in-certain-workspaces-in-visual-studio-code)) and it now looks like this:

```json
{
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    // R Options
    "r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.1\\bin\\R.exe",
    "r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.1\\bin\\Rterm.exe",
    "r.lsp.debug": true,
    "r.lsp.diagnostics": true,
    "r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
    "r.rterm.option": [
        "--no-save",
        "--no-restore",
        "--r-binary=C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.1\\bin\\R.exe"
    ],

    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
               "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
               "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
             ],
             "args": [],
             "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "R": {
            "path": [
                "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.1\\bin\\R.exe"
            ]
        },
     },  

    "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
    "security.workspace.trust.startupPrompt": "never",
    "security.workspace.trust.enabled": false,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "R",
    "terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions" :false
}
```

edit: It seems the problem might be that my user folder contains the Swedish letter "å". Do you know how to handle this problem? Other than chancing my name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few hours of work I found the only solution to the problem: changing the `user folder` of my windows account. The way to do this can be found here: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-change-user-profile-folder-name/